# jquery profile image is not uploading and throwing Exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, model-view-controller

Post a call to server side c# where image file variable get empty/null
function addPersonDetails() {

```
debugger
//var imgUrl = $("#wizard-picture").get(0).files;
var Gander = $('input[name=radioName]:checked', '.radioForm').val();
var param = { //Passing data  
    FirstName: $("#txtfname").val(),
    LastName: $("#txtlname").val(),
    Address: $("#txtadress").val(),
    City: $("#txtcity").val(),
    Email: $("#txtEmail").val(),
    Contact_Mobile: $("#txtContactCell").val(),
    ContactLandline: $("#txtLandline").val(),
    DOB: $("#txtDOB").val(),
    Nationality: $("#txtNationality").val(),
    //Image_Path: imgUrl[0],
    LastDegree: $("#txtDegree").val(),
    Gander: Gander
}


var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("ProfileImage", $('#ProfileImg')[0].files[0]);
fd.append("companyObject", JSON.stringify(param));

$.ajax(
    {
        data: fd,
        type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method  
        url: "/Person/SavePerson", // Controller/View              
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            //alert("here" + data.d.toString());
        }
       });

}
```

When on button click call this function that shows the following error and can not post the call to controller.

[image]

Comment: `Try setting $.ajax({ processData: false})`

Comment: Your given solution solve the following error, but the post call now showing internal server error. when i comment the the code section of "FormData fd" then it work fine.

Comment: The `internal server error` is back end error. You need to check your api or backend code for url `/Person/SavePerson`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("ProfileImage", $('#ProfileImg')[0].files[0]);
fd.append("companyObject", JSON.stringify(param));

 $.ajax({
        url: '/Person/SavePerson',
        processData: false,
        data: fd ,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
                   alert("success");
           
        },
        error: function (result) {
           
            alert(result, "Error: Your function name()");
        }

    });
```

Comment: "try this code".. please elaborate so we can learn. End of Review.